# The accuracy limit of n weak classifier combinations

Tags: math, machine-learning

For dataset D(n * m), n is the number of samples, m is the number of features.
There are k weak classifiers, and the accuracy of each classifier is 60%.
How many weak classifier combinations can improve accuracy to 90%?
Can this problem be solved by mathematical formula?

If use 2 classifiers, the accuracy is 60%
If use 3 classifiers, the accuracy is 64.8%(3 * 60%^2 * 40% + 60%^3)
Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind your question is ensembling.
This can work when each of the model you do choose, perform well for individual classes. So you can assign a weight to each of them according to the classes and generate the final output.

for example,
you have 3 classes (C1, C2, C3)

Let's say Model A, predicts well for C1 then you can set the final probability of C1 as

prob_of_C1=model_A_prob*0.7+model_B_prob*0.2+model_C_prob*0.1

Similarly, you can apply the same rule for other classes. You might have to change the weights you assign and that's generally done based on the precision of each model for that particular class. This will work, only if you have the models performing differently for different classes.

if you want to learn more, you can look at **xgboost alogrithm**, and this blog explains it nicely: [XGBoost Algorithm: Long May She Reign!](https://towardsdatascience.com/https-medium-com-vishalmorde-xgboost-algorithm-long-she-may-rein-edd9f99be63d)

Comment: Sorry, I may not have made my question clear. We only know is that the data has n samples and m-dimensional features，and we can't train model, all weak classifiers are trained. We only can combine them to improve accuracy. So we can't use xgboost or other alogrithm. Under these conditions, bagging(voting) seems to be the only way. Suppose the data has 2 classes.

Comment: Voting is the way to go then.